# Deal with geographical information on international applications

Tags: database, internationalization, geotagging

I am working on a web application that will be deployed into several countries.

I have some content that will be geolocated and then i will have to install some databases with cities name and zipcodes

But, I am thinking about something, all the countries of the world don't have the same geographical hierarchy (For example : Region > Department > Zip Coded City)

Indeed, cities from a country like Ireland don't have any zipcode, some countries don't have departments etc....

So my question is how could we represent geographical data in an application that will work on several countries. The objective is of course to have the same application logic for all countries, just the databases would change depending on location

Thank you in advance!